# Suppose $A \in \mathbb{M}_2(\mathbb R)$ is a non-zero singular matrix. Then, characteristic equation gives $x^2-tr(A)x=0$

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $A \in \mathbb{M}_2(\mathbb R)$ is a non-zero singular matrix. 
Then, characteristic equation gives $x^2-tr(A)x=0$. Now, since from cayley theorem, we have $A^2-tr(A)A=0 \Rightarrow  A(A-tr(A)I)=0$. Now, since $A\neq0$, we have $A=tr(A)\cdot I$. But if, $A=tr(A)\cdot I$ then $A$ is not singular matrix. 
So, how does one find such a matrix?

I was successful in finding a counterexample. The matrix $A$ having $1$ at position $(1,1)$ and $0$ everywhere else in $2\times2$ matrix. Now, $tr(A)=1$ and $A^2=A$. Then $A^2-1\cdot A=0$.
Now, from cayley theorem as explained above $A=I$ as $A$ is non-zero, but it's not singular now.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: For a matrix $A \ne 0$ does NOT mean you can cancel $A$ in your equation.

Comment: Here $A$ is given to be non-zero. So I am allowed right? @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC

Comment: No, you are not allowed to. $A$ would have to be invertible to be able to cancel it. For numbers, non-zero and invertible are the same thing. For matrices they are not.

Comment: And in fact you have explicitly stated that $A$ is singular, i.e. not invertible. So cancelling $A$ is definitely a mistake here.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Please post it as an answer. @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC

Comment: $AB=0$ tells you that the column space of $B$ is a subset of the null space of $A$, but it doesn’t let you conclude that either matrix is zero. There are plenty of nonzero matrices $A$ for which $A^2=0$, for instance.

Comment: @s1mple: Posted it as an answer. Glad to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a matrix, $A \ne 0$ does NOT mean you can cancel $A$ in your equation. $A$ would have to be invertible to be able to cancel it. For numbers, non-zero and invertible are the same thing; for matrices they are not.

And in fact you have explicitly stated that $A$ is singular, i.e. not invertible. So cancelling $A$ is definitely not allowed here.